# PowerBI - How to set thousands separator from DB imported tables

Tags: powerbi, dashboard, separator

Im having issue with PowerBi Dashboard setup. I have imported the data from mssql tables and i want to display numbers with thousands separators to increase readability.
Like: 248754728457 to 248,754,728,457
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UPYn.png)

I really digged through the internet and many stack pages but without a luck. Either have no option in specific tab or other thing.

May you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Alright i finally found it. Maybe it helps somebody:
I went into edit powerquery and set each column as fixed decimal number and applied
then i went into data view (from report view) into column view
then i clicked on the column change its format to decimal number and clicked comma button below as separator.